# Inner join or other equal solution

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have good working  sql query but I need to select also atribute from table advert. I tried with inner join but it wasn't successful. So this query is ok but I need to select one atribute from table advert.

```
SELECT D.* FROM  details 
WHERE (D.name LIKE ?) AND  (D.id_advert IN(
   SELECT A.id 
   FROM advert A 
   WHERE A.status=1 and duration >= CURDATE()  
   ORDER BY duration DESC ))
```

Comment: SELECT D.* FROM  details D  WHERE (D.name LIKE ?) AND  (D.id_advert IN(SELECT A.id FROM advert A WHERE A.status=1 and duration >= CURDATE()  ORDER BY duration DESC )) sorry, I forget to add D to details on post

Comment: Any need for that ORDER BY in the sub-query?

Comment: That query can't be OK, since you're using a table alias D never defined.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `D.name LIKE ?` ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM  details D INNER JOIN advert A on D.id_advert = A.id INNER JOIN place P on A.id_place = P.id WHERE (D.name LIKE ?) AND  (D.id_advert IN(SELECT A.id FROM advert A WHERE A.status=1 and duration >= CURDATE()  ORDER BY duration DESC ))      Here is solution. "?" is for search key. This query work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the in (subquery ) in a proper inner join  and the is simple use the columns form table A

```
SELECT D.* , A.*
FROM  details 
INNER JOIN advert A ON D.id_advert = A.id 
    AND  A.status=1 
    AND duration >= CURDATE()  
WHERE D.name LIKE ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM details D
INNER JOIN advert A ON D.id_advert = A.id
INNER JOIN place P ON A.id_place = P.id
WHERE (D.NAME LIKE ?)
    AND ( D.id_advert IN (
            SELECT A.id
            FROM advert A
            WHERE A.STATUS = 1 AND duration >= CURDATE()
            ORDER BY duration DESC
            )
        )
```

Here "?" is for search key. This query work perfect.